# Divisors of numbers of the form $a^2+2b^2$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, quadratic-forms

Let's say I have a number $n$ which can be written as $a^2+2b^2$ for integers $a,b$. By Fermat/Euler/*etc.*, I know that the primes dividing the squarefree kernel of $n$ cannot be congruent to $5$ or $7$ modulo $8$. But does the additional restriction $\gcd(a,b)=1$ give me any additional information? My intuition (and some brute-force searches) leads me to believe that *no* prime — even a prime to an even power — dividing $n$ can be congruent to $5$ or $7$ modulo $8$.

Comment: Nope, there are really no other conditions. A number can be represented in that form exactly if all its prime factors are $p=2$ or $p\equiv 1,3\pmod 8$, because $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a UFD.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: But $5^2+2 \cdot 5^2=75=3 \cdot 5^2$, right?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan Except that you started by requiring gcd=1

Comment: Yep, unless I'm forgetting my number theory, $5$ and $5$ have a common factor.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan Maybe I am getting confused. Are you asking if we can find $a,b$ with no common factor such that $a^2+2b^2$ is divisible by a prime $p=5$ or 7 mod 8?

Comment: You are correct, if $(a,b)=1$ then if $p\mid a^2+2b^2$ then $-2$ is a square modulo $p$.

Comment: @almagest: Yes, that's essentially my question. Is there a number $n=a^2+2b^2$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ divisible by a prime $p \equiv 5$ or $7$ mod $8$. I apologise that my question and the title together are, indeed, confusing.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan Thanks for the correction and apology, but it was my fault, I am totally washed out today and did not read your question carefully enough. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $p\mid a^2+2b^2$ then $p$ is not a factor of $b$, so $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2=-2\pmod p$, so $-2$ must be a square modulo $p$, which is possible exactly when $p=2$ or $p\equiv 1,3\pmod 8$.

Since $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a unique factorization domain, you can use the same argument that we use for the two square theorem to show that every number with no prime factors $p\equiv 5,7\pmod 8$can be written as $a^2+2b^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2   $$ with
$$  \Delta = b^2 - 4 a c $$ which, if non-negative, is not allowed to be $0$ or $1$ or any square. Also demand $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1.$

Theorem. Given **odd** prime $q$  that does not divide $\Delta,$ with
$ (\Delta|q) = -1,  $ whenever
$$  f(x,y) \equiv 0 \pmod q, $$
then 
$$   x,y \equiv 0 \pmod q $$ THEREFORE
$$  f(x,y) \equiv 0 \pmod {q^2}. $$

PROOF: by the hypothesis, $a$ is not divisible by $q.$ Multiply through by $4a$ and complete the square.

In comparison, for odd primes $p$ not dividing the discriminant, with  $ (\Delta|p) = +1,  $ there are no restrictions. This is, for example, Lemma 2.4 on page 58 of [CASSELS](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html), inexpensive reprint and very good.

The prime $2$ and primes dividing the discriminant should be handled separately. There are also general rules but more is going on.